# Aggregation by field and then sum value of another field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I need to aggregate by one field and then, in the same aggregation, calculate sum with another field value. But when execute the query the first aggregation is ok but the sum is always 0.

Example index:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "transaction": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": {
                "transaction": {
                    "properties": {
                        "amount": {
                            "type": "double"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "infrastructureElement": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "infrastructureElementSubType": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the query below, aggregate by `infrastructureElement.infrastructureElementSubType` and then sum the value `transactionPurchase.amount` in another aggs:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_infrastructure_element": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "infrastructureElement"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "group_by_ie_subtype": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "infrastructureElement.infrastructureElementSubType"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "revenue": {
                            "sum": {
                                "field": "transactionPurchase.amount"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Current result:

```
{
    "took": 6,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
    ...
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "group_by_infrastructure_element": {
            "doc_count": 365,
            "group_by_ie_subtype": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": "MOBILE",
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "revenue": {
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to make use of [Reverse Nested Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html) and then chain in the [Sum Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html) for calculating what you are looking for:

### Aggregation Query:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "myterms":{  
         "nested":{  
            "path":"infrastructureElement"
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "myterms":{  
               "terms":{  
                  "field":"infrastructureElement.infrastructureElementSubType",
                  "size":10
               },
               "aggs":{  
                  "reverse":{  
                     "reverse_nested":{},
                     "aggs":{  
                        "revenue":{  
                           "sum":{  
                              "field":"transaction.amount"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Also notice how your mapping is structured, the field `transaction` is not a [`Nested Type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) but a simple [`Object Type`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html). Now, if you are inside the nested aggregation, you would need to traverse back to the root and then perform the metric aggregation for e.g. sum in order to calculate the `amount`

Note the below response for the sample documents I've created.

```
POST someaggregation/_doc/1
{
  "transaction":{
    "amount": 100
  },
  "infrastructureElement": [
    {
      "infrastructureElementSubType": "type1"
    },
    {
      "infrastructureElementSubType": "type2"
    }
  ]
}

POST someaggregation/_doc/2
{
  "transaction":{
    "amount": 100
  },
  "infrastructureElement": [
    {
      "infrastructureElementSubType": "type1"
    },
    {
      "infrastructureElementSubType": "type2"
    }
  ]
}

POST someaggregation/_doc/3
{
  "transaction":{
    "amount": 100
  },
  "infrastructureElement": [
    {
      "infrastructureElementSubType": "type3"
    },
    {
      "infrastructureElementSubType": "type4"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 519,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "myterms" : {
      "doc_count" : 6,
      "myterms" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "type1",
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "reverse" : {
              "doc_count" : 2,
              "revenue" : {
                "value" : 200.0
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "type2",
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "reverse" : {
              "doc_count" : 2,
              "revenue" : {
                "value" : 200.0
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "type3",
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "reverse" : {
              "doc_count" : 1,
              "revenue" : {
                "value" : 100.0
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key" : "type4",
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "reverse" : {
              "doc_count" : 1,
              "revenue" : {
                "value" : 100.0
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Feel free to upvote and/or accept this answer if you think this solves your problem :)

Comment: Just perfect @Kamal, thanks a lot it work fine :) `transaction` is a `Object Type` because my real index is more complex. In the same index i have more transaction type objects (ie. purchase, validation...) with more properties.